# Validate form based on array values

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation

I'm new to jQuery and coding in general and was wondering if anyone could give me a hand.

I have two input fields (#cp1 & #cp2) a submit button (#enter) and two arrays (arr1 & arr2).

```
arr1 = ["1700", "1000", "1749"];

arr2 = ["001", "002", "003"];
```

`#cp1` should be: digits only; max 4 digits; min 4 digits; and validated only if its value equals a value in `arr1`.

`#cp2` should be: digits only; max 3 digits; min 3 digits; and validated only if its value equals a value in `arr2`.

Upon pressing #enter it should check if both #cp1 and #cp2 are true or not and return the appropriate alert message.

Here's my HTML:

```
<input id="cp1" type="text" maxlength="4" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></input> 
<input id="cp2" type="text" maxlength="3" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></input> 
<button type="submit" id="enter">Confirmar</button>
```

I can get it right if I only have a variable for each input but I don't know how to make it search within the arrays for the right values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tamefyp2/)):

```
arr1 = ["1700", "1000", "1749"];

arr2 = ["001", "002", "003"];

$(function() {
    $("#enter").click(function() {
        if(jQuery.inArray($("#cp1").val(), arr1) == -1)
            alert('Value not in first array');
        if(jQuery.inArray($("#cp2").val(), arr2) == -1)
            alert('Value not in second array');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped! Playing around with this I eventually found that I can't do it like I had originally thought.
Actually I just need one array ex: ["1700-001", "1000-002", "1749-003"...] and have the input field split into two with the "-" separating them (so the user only has to type the digits). The user would enter something like "1700001" and the "-" would be added automatically for comparison with the array values. Can this be done? Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. You just need to build a string out of the values yourself. [Here's what that would look like](http://jsfiddle.net/tamefyp2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following demo. It uses a `data` attribute and `arr.filter` to perform validation and puts the arrays in an object.

```js
$(function() {
  var varr = {
    arr1: ["1700", "1000", "1749"],
    arr2: ["001", "002", "003"]
  };
  $('[data-arr]').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var arr = $(this).data('arr'),
      key = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode),
      val = this.value,
      fnd = varr[arr].filter(function(v) {
        return v.slice(0, val.length + 1) == val + key;
      });
    if(!fnd.length) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    console.log(arr, key, val, fnd);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cp1" data-arr="arr1" type="text" maxlength="4"></input>
<input id="cp2" data-arr="arr2" type="text" maxlength="3"></input>
<button type="submit" id="enter">Confirmar</button>
```